# Audio file opened by itself?

Tags: audio, malware, k9-mail, stagefright

This morning I woke up to the alarm on my phone, as I snoozed it I noticed that the Total Commander player had a notification open, with an audio file open but on hold.

When I tapped on play I got the Total Commander warning about Stagefright and asking me to confirm I really wanted to play the file, to which I answered no.

In the process I unfortunately also involuntarily closed TC before I could fully see what the file being played was, but I noticed it was from a fsck.k9 folder (so like an attachment I guess).

However I haven't received any audio files in attachment in the last few days and data, wifi and bluetooth were all off during the night.

I have done a scan with Bitdefender which hasn't evidenced any malware. I haven't installed any suspicious apps recently.

Any ideas of what could have happened?

Edit: Android 5.0.2 on a Moto E
Edit2: I do use K-9 for email (hence my reference to audio attachments)

Comment: Please [edit] to mention Android version and device details

Comment: Do you use k9 mail? (com.fsck.k9.mail: https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It [seems](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/208598) that you have lost access to your account. To regain access or to merge your multiple accounts, please follow the link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).